# slow Graphics on Ubuntu 18.04, on Dell(Intel graphics drivers), while watching Youtube videos

Tags: graphics, 18.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

while watching videos(Youtube) it freezes for about 5-10 seconds and then continues but audio keeps running.
I tried in different browsers, but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are watching the youtube videos within the browser and they are at a somewhat higher resolution, this is the expected behaviour. Keep in mind that **none of the available web browsers on Linux support hardware accelerated video decoding**, even if the underlying system supports it. Most people don't notice this because they have a CPU that is fast enough. They should notice though because this causes very high CPU usage and battery drain.

Unfortunately this is where all common Linux web browsers are lacking support compared to those on other popular operating systems.

The only way to work around that problem currently is to download the video in some way and watch it using a dedicated application that can make use of hardware accelerated video decoding, like `mpv` or `vlc`.

With `mpv` you can even directly copy the youtube URL from the browser window to the command line and stream the video:

```
mpv "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzyw6W_njls"
```

Do not forget the quotes. (using random video URL here for demonstration purposes). You can choose the format and codec parameters by specifying parameters like this:

```
mpv --ytdl-format="bestvideo[height<=?240]" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzyw6W_njls"
```

Above would limit the video to a format with a vertical resolution equal or less than 240 pixels (240p). To list avialable formats use:

```
youtube-dl -F "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzyw6W_njls"
```

See the section about `--ytdl-format` in the [mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) for more information.

Comment: but when I was using Ubuntu 16.04, it was working well with 1080p resolution youtube videos. but I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and now it has this problem. Is any package or driver is missing from Ubuntu 18.04 version, compared to previous?

Comment: also, why the same issue doesn't happen at Windows 10, as I have Ubuntu dual booted with it, Youtube videos work fine on Windows.

Comment: I have accepted answer but just one doubt, can we choose quality of video from command line like you said  `mpv "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzyw6W_njls"?`

Comment: which browsers support default hardware acceleration of video playback?

Comment: @ganesh10 I added (and moved from comments) some more information to my answer

Comment: @ganesh10, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelQuickSyncVideo gives good information on the hardware acceleration issue, as does https://forum.manjaro.org/t/is-there-a-browser-on-linux-that-supports-hardware-accelerated-video-playback-vp9/35003/6 , https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/662dxm/psa_hardware_acceleration_on_firefox_may_be/ and https://helgeklein.com/blog/2017/12/browser-video-codecs-formats-hardware-acceleration/ .

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed several such posts  and examined many of the responses and determined that  no one has yet (that I've seen) quite understood the problem.

### All the fixes I've seen were very  complex and assumed some change  should be made to the system.

You tube videos and other videos  run in a very slow speed.  Videos stored on the computer also run at a very slow speed and there is no sound.

### This has happened to me on a Dell Ispiron.  There were no remarkable upgrades  or installations no large alterations in the system prior to this happening,  one day it just started happening.

THIS IS WHAT SOLVED THE PROBLEM FOR ME
turn off the laptop
Unplug the laptop
Remove the battery
 put it all back together and Poof  problem solved.

Comment: I've not noticed any really slow youtube on my quite old Dell Lattitude, with Ubuntu 18.10 - I'm unsure why removing and reinstalling the batter would change the web performance either....

Comment: I can't tell you why other than to guess that something  is clogging the process up in a way I don't understand but that remains  unless the power is killed.  But  my ability to play a video was  interrupted by a deathly slowness  one frame every 30 or 40 seconds and no sound.   The solutions I found on Ubuntu forums were useless.  Killing the power worked.